# LINQ: select rows where any word of string start with a certain character

Tags: linq

I want extract from a table all rows where in a column (string) there is at least one word that starts with a specified character.
Example:

```
Row 1: 'this is the first row'
Row 2: 'this is th second row'
Row 3: 'this is the third row'
```

If the specified character is T -> I would extract all 3 rows
If the specified character is S -> I would extract only the second column
...

Please help me

Comment: Can you provide a precise definition for "word"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "space delimited sequence of characters, or begin to space or space to end" by "word", then you can split on the delimiter and test them for matches:

```
var src = new[] {
    "this is the first row",
    "this is th second row",
    "this is the third row"
};

var findChar = 'S';
var lowerFindChar = findChar.ToLower();
var matches = src.Where(s => s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(w => w.ToLower()[0] == lowerFindChar));
```

The LINQ `Enumerable.Any` method [tests a sequence to see if any element matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__), so you can split each string into a sequence of words and see if any word begins with the desired letter, compensating for case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rows.Where(r => Regex.IsMatch(r, " [Tt]"))
```

You can replace the `Tt` with `Ss` (both assuming you want either upper case or lower case).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of course is, what is a "word"?

Is the character sequence 'word' in the sentence above a word according to your definition? It doesn't start with a space, not even a white-space.

A definition of a word could be:

Define **wordCharacter**: something like A-Z, a-z.
Define **word**: 
 - the non-empty sequence of wordCharacters at the beginning of a string followed by a non-wordcharacter
 - or the non-empty sequence of wordCharacters at the end of a string preceded by a non-wordcharacter
 - any non-empty sequence of wordCharacters in the string preceded and followed by a non-wordcharacter
Define **start of word**: the first character of a word.

String: "Some strange characters: 'A', 9, äll, B9 C$ X?
- Words: Some, strange characters, A 
- Not Words: 9, äll, B9, C$ X?

So you first have to specify precisely what you mean by word, then you can define functions.

I'll write it as an extension method of `IEnumerable<string>`. Usage will look similar to LINQ. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
bool IsWordCharacter(char c) {... TODO: implement your definition of word character}

static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoWords(this string text)
{
    // TODO: exception if text null
    if (text.Length == 0) return 

    int startIndex = 0;
    while (startIndex != text.Length)
    {   // not at end of string. Find the beginning of the next word:
        while (startIndex < text.Length && !IsWordCharacter(text[startIndex])) 
        {
            ++startIndex;
        }

        // now startIndex points to the first character of the next word
        // or to the end of the text

        if (startIndex != text.Length)
        {   // found the beginning of a word.
            // the first character after the word is either the first non-word character,
            // or the end of the string

            int indexAfterWord = startWordIndex + 1;
            while (indexAfterWord < text.Length && IsWordCharacter(text[indexAfterWord]))
            {
                ++indexAfterWord;
            }

            // all characters from startIndex to indexAfterWord-1 are word characters
            // so all characters between startIndexWord and indexAfterWord-1 are a word
            int wordLength = indexAfterWord - startIndexWord;
            yield return text.SubString(startIndexWord, wordLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you've got a procedure to split any string into your definition of words, your query will be simple:

```
IEnumerabl<string> texts = ...
char specifiedChar = 'T';

// keep only those texts that have at least one word that starts with specifiedChar:
var textsWithWordThatStartsWithSpecifiedChar = texts
    // split the text into words
    // keep only the words that start with specifiedChar
    // if there is such a word: keep the text
    .Where(text => text.SplitIntoWords()
                   .Where(word => word.Length > 0 && word[0] == specifiedChar)
                   .Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourChar = "s";

var texts = new List<string> {
    "this is the first row",
    "this is th second row",
    "this is the third row"
};

var result = texts.Where(p => p.StartsWith(yourChar) || p.Contains(" " + yourChar));
```

EDITED:

Alternative way (I'm not sure it works in linq query)

```
var result = texts.Where(p => (" " + p).Contains(" " + yourChar));
```

- you can use .ToLower() if  you want Case-insensitive check.